# Universal Windows 10 App Using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I started learning Windows app development using Visual Studio 2015 following this article: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Phone-Login-17725566

In my solution I created two directories, one for Views (xaml) and another for Models (xaml.cs). Up to the creation of my xaml files everything went smoothly. When it comes to xaml.cs (assume now I'm in a login page), when I click the login button, it should go to the signup page.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace LoginApp.Model
{
    class LoginPage

    {

        public void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        }
        public void SiguUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/SignUpPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));


        }

    }
}
```

I have an issue with NavigationService (It is saying "the name NavigationService does not exist in current context").

The second point where I'm stuck is in the signup Page.xaml.cs. I have a textbox with the name `txtusername`. I'm trying to add some text to the textbox and use a message box:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace LoginApp.Model
{
    class SignUpPage
    {

        IsolatedStorageFile ISOFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        public void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

            if (!Regex.IsMatch(TxtUserName.Text.Trim(), @"^[A-Za-z_][a-zA-Z0-9_\s]*$")) {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid UserName");

            }

        }

    }
}


<Page
    x:Class="LoginApp.SignUpPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:LoginApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid Margin="10,10,-5,-10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="User Registration :" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="40" Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBlock Text="UserName" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Black" Margin="0,25,0,0"/>
            <TextBox Name="TxtUserName" BorderBrush="LightGray" Grid.Row="1" Margin="100,0,0,0" GotFocus="Txt_GotFocus"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Password:" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,25,0,0" Foreground="Black"/>
            <PasswordBox Name="TxtPwd" BorderBrush="LightGray" Grid.Row="2" Margin="100,0,0,0" GotFocus="pwd_GotFocus"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Address:" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,25,0,0" Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBox Name="TxtAddr" BorderBrush="LightGray" Margin="100,0,0,0" GotFocus="Txt_GotFocus"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Gender:" Grid.Row="4" Margin="0,25,0,0" Foreground="Black"/>
            <RadioButton Name="GenMale" Background="LightGray" Grid.Row="4" Margin="100,0,0,0" Content="Male" Foreground="Black"/>
            <RadioButton Name="GenFemale" Background="LightGray" Grid.Row="4" Margin="200,0,0,0" Content="Female" Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Phone No:" Grid.Row="5" Margin="0,25,0,0" Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBox Name="TxtPhNo" Grid.Row="5" Margin="100,0,0,0" Foreground="LightGray" MaxLength="10" InputScope="Digits" GotFocus="Txt_GotFocus"/>
            <TextBlock Text="EmailID:" Grid.Row="6" Margin="0,25,0,0" Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBox Name="TxtEmail" Grid.Row="6" Margin="100,0,0,0" GotFocus="TxtGotFocus"/>
            <Button BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="#FF30DABB" Content="Submit" Name="BtnSubmit" Click="Submit_Click" Grid.Row="7" Margin="0,25.667,0,-41.667" Width="345"/>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

With this code the red line points to the TxtUserName and MessageBox saying that "The name does not exist in current context".

I found one article in the it is saying "use correct reference Add Reference to PresentationFramework.dll". I added a reference and clicked Select Assemblies > Framework > Check the PresentationFramework component box and clicked ok.

When I reach this point, it is showing "No Framework assemblies were found on the machine".

I have .NET Framework 4.5 installed on my computer.

Comment: Your tutorial is not for UWP apps, but for Windows Phone 7.x/8.x which, while similar, is different, hence your errors.

Comment: Can You suggest any other example to try??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird, I pasted your code and launched the app, its working fine and I am able to display Text and Textbox is visible:

[image]

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TxtUserName.Text = "Sample text!";
    }
```

Maybe there is some other problem with your project?

Answer (score 1):

1. Navigation in the Uiniversal Windows Apps has changed. To navigate between pages you have to use below code:

   ```
   Frame.Navigate(typeof(NameOfYourPage)));
   ```

   You can also pass some parameters (object type is expected):

   ```
   Frame.Navigate(typeof(NameOfYourPage), YourClassObject));
   ```

In your case:

```
public void SiguUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
   Frame.Navigate(typeof(SignUpPage)));
}
```

2. To add some text to your TextBox control you should use "Text" property:

   ```
   YourTextBox.Text = "This is sample text";
   ```

YourTextBox control has to be declared in the Page's XAML code:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="YourTextBox"/>
```

Comment: public void SiguUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            // NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/SignUpPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            Frame.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/SignUpPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));


        }

Comment: Frame.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/SignUpPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

Comment: I added this line still it is saying The name does not exist in the current context

Comment: if (!Regex.IsMatch(TxtUserName.Text.Trim(), @"^[A-Za-z_][a-zA-Z0-9_\s]*$")) {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid UserName");

            }

Comment: Do you mean line with textbox? Did you declare it in the Xaml code of SignUpPage Page?

Comment: For text box I did same thing In above line TxtUserName is the name of TextBox@danny

Comment: <TextBox Name="TxtUserName" BorderBrush="LightGray" Grid.Row="1" Margin="100,0,0,0" GotFocus="Txt_GotFocus"/>

Comment: Could you please paste the whole xaml code and code behind of SignUpPage page? I will try to go through it.

Comment: Can you go through the article which I shared ?@Rowland saw mention those errors because of the windows version??

Comment: You should of course create Universal Windows Project in the Visual Studio (not 8.1 or earlier).
Check this:
https://mobileprogrammerblog.files.wordpress.com/2016/05/win10toast2.png?w=660&h=349

Comment: You can also check my blog post with step by step creating Universal Windows 10 App:
https://mobileprogrammerblog.wordpress.com/2015/08/23/first-windows-10-universal-application-jump-start/